# SQL count not returning the proper count

Tags: c#, sql

I have this sql query which should return a count of 0 but I guess it is badly build.

here is the SQL code which I execute

```
string cmdText = @"SELECT count(*) 
                   From Apointement 
                   WHERE emailClient=@emailClient AND 
                       trialdate=@trialdate AND 
                       TrailHour=trialhour";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailClient", Convert.ToString(Session["email"]));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trialdate",dDateApt);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trialhour", sHourApt);

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}

int nbrofRec = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (nbrofRec >= 1)
```

This query return 1 for the count.

The data in the query is as follow:

```
email     = s.brown@rv.com  
trialdate = 1/27/2014 12:00:00AM  
trialhour = 10:00
```

The date in the database

```
email     = s.brown@rv.com  
trialdate = 1/27/2014 
trialhour = 12:00       <=== notice the only appointment is at 12:00 not at 10:00
```

I can't find out which element is wrong.

Comment: Simple typo, but it is curious the reason why there is no error message.  `TrialHour=trialhour` it is always true

Comment: @Steve Yeah, I was wondering about that too :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
AND TrailHour=trialhour
```

should be

```
AND TrailHour=@trialhour
```

Comment: possibly it should be `AND TrialHour=@trialhour`

Comment: Yes, could be any kinds of errors in there :)

Comment: thanks I didn't see it....

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `@` in front of last parameter.

So make your SQL like so.

```
string cmdText = "SELECT count(*) From Apointement WHERE emailClient=@emailClient AND 
           trialdate=@trialdate AND TrailHour=@Trialhour"
```

Comment: Not a big deal, but I put a `@` before the string input so it could be multi-lined.